# Use Puppeteer.js on different OS (Windows, Raspbian)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer

In my project, I use Puppeteer to take screenshots on Tradingview.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function captureChartScreenshot(symbol, interval) {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: "new"
    });

    try {
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        const chartUrl = `https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=${symbol}&interval=${interval}`;

        await page.goto(chartUrl);

        // Attendi che il grafico TradingView sia completamente caricato
        await page.waitForSelector('.chart-gui-wrapper');

        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1200,
            height: 600,
        });

        // Seleziona l'elemento del grafico
        const graficoElement = await page.$('.chart-container');

        // Prendi le dimensioni dell'elemento del grafico
        const graficoBoundingBox = await graficoElement.boundingBox();

        // Prendi lo screenshot solo dell'elemento del grafico
        const screenshotBuffer = await graficoElement.screenshot({
            clip: {
                x: graficoBoundingBox.x,
                y: graficoBoundingBox.y,
                width:      Math.min(graficoBoundingBox.width, page.viewport().width),
                height:     Math.min(graficoBoundingBox.height, page.viewport().height),
            },
        });

        await browser.close();

        return screenshotBuffer;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}
```

When I run bot.js in vscode on Windows, the bot correctly sends messages with the attached image. However, when I run bot.js on a Raspberry Pi, the messages with the Puppeteer screenshot are not sent, and I receive this error:

> 19/7/2023, 15:49:27
> Error at row: /home/pi/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-114.0.5735.133/chrome-linux64/chrome: 1: /home/pi/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-114.0.5735.133/chrome-linux64/chrome: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
> Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
> /home/pi/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-114.0.5735.133/chrome-linux64/chrome: 1: /home/pi/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-114.0.5735.133/chrome-linux64/chrome: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

However, I haven't figured out how to fix this on the Raspberry Pi.

I tried reinstalling NPM and updating the Chrome version, but without success.

Comment: Did you check if the browser binary is launchable on ARM processor? E.g Raspberry? You said that it works on Windows, maybe this is the problem, also even though you update the chrome version, it seems that he's trying to launch the browser from the .cache folder and not from your system.

Comment: @FernandoZamperin Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it. From what I understood, the error is caused by the fact that the browser cannot open, but I really didn't understand the reason.

Comment: As I said, if the browser is compiled using different architecture it will not work on your raspberry, you have to configure puppeteer to use your system browser

Comment: Hy @FernandoZamperin, can u explain to me please, how can i configure the raspi for use the system browser?